# Android Studio NDK : /Path/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/cxx-stl/system/include/cstring string.h not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android) to read the source code, but however, when I run the command that `./gradlew androidDebug --stacktrace`

It shows that

```
/home/kolibreath/AndroidStudioProjects/
music-synthesizer-for-android/app/src/main/jni/synth_unit.cc:22:10: 
fatal error: 'android/log.h' file not found
#include <android/log.h>
```

and something more like this. So I look into the file, there is no string.h under in it. I directly download the ndk from `sdk-manager` which is the lastest version.

The platform I use is Ubuntu and I build the project once before, the project was built successfully and ran on my tablet. But when I reinstall Ubuntu again, after I almost download everything on the machine before, the gradlew failed.

Can anyone point out where I go wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [project](https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android) uses the outdated *experimental* gradle plugin, and has not been updated to comply with the latest NDK release. Google provides instructions how to move on to the ***Stable*** gradle for NDK support using CMake or ndk-build [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable).

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you very much, the project indeed uses a very old plugin.